# Meteor reactivity without autorun()?

Tags: meteor, angular, reactive-programming, angular-meteor

Here is my root component in angular-meteor app:

```
export class RootComponent implements OnInit {
    playlists:Mongo.Cursor<any>;

    ngOnInit():any {
        this.playlists = Playlists.find();
    }

}
```

When I update `Playlist` collection from another angular(2) component, I see that my view where I am rendering the playlists updates.
That particular view does not have access to any other variable in the other component so it seems obvious that the view is updating because of collection playlist updating.

I was wondering that how is this happening without having that code in `ngOnInit` update the view without being in `Tracker.autorun`?

Comment: What you are seeing is the publish/subscribe mechanism at work. You only need to use Tracker when you have something that you want to make reactive. Meteor does some magic to make life easy for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Tracker.autorun()` is a way to explicitly create a computation object around some data that you want to be reactive. However, certain things are automatically reactive in Meteor:

- Session variables
- Template helpers
- Publish/subcribe statements
- Collection cursors

See here for more info: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactivity-basics-meteors-magic-demystified/

Comment: Actually I realized that the Cursors are also reactive by default. So pls edit your answer to include cursors as well